# How to convert a string to long int?

Tags: programming

I'm new to Arduino and my first project is an RFID reader. since I need a lot of known tags list , i have a problem with not enough memory. for that reason I want to convert strings like :  "426d9244", "1265dd39"... to a long int. I know it's been asked but as a new programer I find it hard to understand. an example would be very appreciated also.

Comment: You could use the atol() function. However, I think that is not your problem. Perhaps you have blocks of code that is repeated a few times. Do you use the Serial.println in combination with the F() macro?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you want to do with the 'd'or 'dd'in between.

You can check some functions:

1. strtok: which can split a string based on delimiters (in your case probably 'd'). Than you get an array of strings (e.g. for the first: { "426", "9244"}.
2. For each string ("426" and "9244") you use function atol to convert it into a long integer.

Answer (score 1):

If all those are known tags, you can put them in the source code as
32 bit integers. No
need to convert. Or rather, let the compiler do the conversion:

```
const uint32_t ID_num[ARRAYSIZE] PROGMEM = {
    Oxbcc0f1c3, Ox821a7d39, Ox4924887c, ...
};
```

When you read a tag number in hex, in order to compare it with the known
tags, you convert it to the same type using [`strtoul()` from
avr-libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaea44aa48bda8261f794dcb2d1e7ab2b2):

```
uint32_t tag_id = strtoul(tag_string, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Actualy , it did the compare without even converting the tag_id... , it works perfect now,  HOGE thanks!!!

Comment: Please "accept" the answer to show that it helped you. Thanks!